# associated models in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I think I may be missing something here or my understanding of rails model association isnt quite there yet (still learning). I have two models, a recipe and a ingredient. A recipe has many ingredients, and when i fill my form in i want to post recipe and ingredient params to their respective dbs

Recipe Model

```
 class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :dish_name, :country_of_origin, :difficulty, :preperation_time
 has_many :ingredients

 end
```

Ingredients Model

```
 class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :recipe
attr_accessible :ingredients
end
```

recipe controller

```
 def new 

 @recipe = Recipe.new

 end

 def create

 @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
 if @recipe.valid?
 @recipe.save
 redirect_to recipes_path, :notice => "Recipe sucessfully created."
 else
 flash.now.alert = "Please ensure all fields are filled in."
 render :new

 end
end
```

Ingredients Controller

```
  def new
  @ingredient = recipes.find(params[:recipes_id].ingredients.new
  @recipe_id = params[:recipe_id]
  end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @recipe  do |f| %>

<%= f.label :dish_name, "Dish Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :dish_name, :placeholder => "Enter Dish Name" %>

more fields here(wanted to keep as short as poss)

<%= f.label :ingredients, "Ingredients" %>
<%= f.text_field :ingredients , :class => :ingred, :placeholder => "Enter Ingredient Here" %><br>
<% end %>
```

Apologies for the size of the code, is anything else needed to see why i cannot create a recipe?

Comment: Why is it that you "cannot create a recipe?" Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, does your Ingredient model include a foreign key column like "recipe_id"?

Also, if the ingredients for a given recipe are just stored in a single text string, why not just make that a column in your recipe model instead of creating a second model?  Alternatively, if you are going to have multiple ingredients tied to a single recipe, you should look into forms with nested model attributes.  There's a good rails cast on it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something link this...

---MODELS---

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :dish_name, :country_of_origin, :difficulty, :preperation_time, :ingredients_collection
 has_many :ingredients
 def ingredients_collection
   self.ingredients.collect(&:name).join(" ,")  
 end
 def ingredients_collection(ingredients)
   ingredients.each do |ingredient|
   i = Ingredient.create(:name => ingredient)    
   self.ingredients << i
 end
 end
 end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  attr_accessible :name # you should have some valid attribute name as it would conflict with the ingredients which is a method defined by the association (:has_many) in the instance of the Recipe...
  end
```

----CONTROLLER----

```
def new
 @recipe = Recipe.new
end
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
  if @recipe.save # no need to call the valid the validations would take care of it by themselves
    redirect_to recipes_path, :notice => "Recipe sucessfully created."
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Please ensure all fields are filled in."
    render :new
  end
end
```

no need to define the controller for the ingredients...you would be defining the ingredient from the particular Recipe from the recipe instance only...

---FORM---

```
 <%= form_for @recipe  do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :dish_name, "Dish Name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :dish_name, :placeholder => "Enter Dish Name" %>
      more fields here(wanted to keep as short as poss)
   <%= f.label :ingredients, "Ingredients" %>
   <%= f.text_field :ingredients_collection , :class => :ingred, :placeholder => "Enter Ingredient Here" %><br>
  <% end %>
```

I would still suggest that you study about the virtual attributes and I guess it would fit in perfectly given your situation and needs...

Read about the virtual attributes from http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes